# Sending mail from c#.net

Tags: c#

I wrote this code in c# to send email to perticular userid
it was working fine from local host

But today I hosted in server
but after hosting email was not sent
"messaging sending failed" - This error is displaying
This is code I written

Please give any sugession

```
string msg = "Welcome to India";
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("email_from@gmail.com", email_to@gmail.com, "subject", msg);

mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("email_from@gmail.com", "password");
sc.EnableSsl = true;
sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
sc.Credentials = nc;
sc.Send(mm);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? Please put a try catch and log the exception using File operations

Comment: We need more details. What is exactly exception? On which line?

Comment: Server firewall might be blocking port `587`, or it might be blocking any request to `gmail`, or gmail has disabled sending mails from that smtp account or... This question is very, very vague.

Comment: Definitely check the firewall. Was there an inner exception?

Answer (score 1):

Even if your server is not blocking the connection, Google might also block your application from accessing their server. Recently I've tried to do the same and got the following email from Google:

> Amit,
>
> Someone recently tried to use an application to sign in to your Google
>   Account - xyz@gmail.com. We prevented the sign-in attempt in case this
>   was a hijacker trying to access your account. Please review the
>   details of the sign-in attempt:
>
> Monday, 4 February 2013 17:48:12 o'clock UTC IP Address:
>   108.163.248.10 Location: United States
>
> If you do not recognise this sign-in attempt, someone else might be
>   trying to access your account. You should sign in to your account and
>   reset your password immediately. Find out how at
>   http://support.google.com/accounts?p=reset_pw
>
> If this was you, and you want to give this application access to your
>   account, complete the troubleshooting steps listed at
>   http://support.google.com/mail?p=client_login
>
> Note: This email address cannot accept replies.
>
> Yours sincerely, The Google Accounts Team

I just clicked on troubleshooting link and did as directed and my problem was solved.
You should check if you've also got a similar email from Google.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to remove your email from your post, unless you want those pesky bots to harvest it :P